# Explanation of semidirect products

Tags: abstract-algebra, semidirect-product

I have been reading many pdfs and books about abstract algebra, covering almost completely the topic of groups. Fortunately, I have been able to understand almost everything with the exception of semidirect products.
As I have seen, if one has two groups $H,K$, one can define the semidirect product as $(h_1,k_1)(h_2,k_2) = (h_1\phi_{k_1}(h_2),k_1k_2)$, where $\phi: K \rightarrow Aut(H)$. The definition seems right (however, it would be nice if someone could confirme it), but I get struck when trying to calculate, for example, all the semidirect products between $\mathbb{Z}_4$ and $\mathbb{Z}_7$. Another important point of this concept is knowing how to calculate all groups given a certain order, so I would be really grateful if someone could help me to extend my comprehension in this topic and to get all the semidirect products given the certain groups I have mentioned before, which were just an example.

Comment: Do you mean that you are unable to find all homomorphisms $\phi: \mathbb{Z}_4\to Aut(\mathbb{Z}_7)$?

Comment: I'd rather say that I can't find all the semidirect products between $\mathbb{Z}_4$ and $\mathbb{Z}_7$

Comment: Yes Daniel, but where exactly is your problem? (i) Can you find all the homms as I asked? (ii) Can you prove that the product you define on $H\times K$ does give a group structure? [this is in the textbooks] (iii) if not these, what?

Comment: For instance, I just have seen an exercise which says exactly: "Find all possible semidirect products between $C_3$ and $C_3$", where $C_3$ is the cyclic group of order 3 (isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_3$). This is the same as with the example of Z4 an Z7, but with $C_3$. How would be the answer of this exercise? Besides, I don't know how to find those homms.. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Semidirect products of $\mathbb{Z}_7$ by $\mathbb{Z}_4$.

In $\mathbb{Z}_7$ every non-identity element has order $7$ and so is a generator. To fix notation let $s$ be one of the generators. Clearly an automorphism of $\mathbb{Z}_7$ carries a generator to a generator; and conversely any map carry a generator to a generator provides one automorphism.  Then there are $6$ automorphisms, $\alpha_r: y^m\mapsto y^{mr}$ with $r=1,2,\dots,6$.

Now fix notation by letting $f$ be a generator of $\mathbb{Z}_4$.  We are seeking homomorphisms $\phi:\mathbb{Z}_4\to \{\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_6\}$. Now we have $f^4=1$ and so $\phi(f)^4=1$. That is, the element $\phi(f)$ has order dividing $4$, that is one of $1,2,4$.

It is an easy calculation to see that $\alpha_1$ has order $1$ and that $\alpha_6$ has order $2$; and that all the other $\alpha_r$ have orders $3$ or $6$.

So there are two possible homomorphisms $\phi:\mathbb{Z}_4\to \{\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_6\}$. There is $\phi_0:f\mapsto \alpha_1$ and $\phi_1:f\mapsto \alpha_6$.

There are therefore two semidirect products.

With $\phi_0$ note that $\alpha_1$ is the identity map, and so by your definition of how the multiplication is defined we have $(y^i, f^j)(y^I,f^J)=(y^{i+I},f^{j+J})$. (The indices are to be calculated mod $7$ and mod $4$ of course.) This is just the direct product.

With $\phi_1$ note that $\alpha_6$ is the map that inverts $y$ and each of its powers. So by your definition of how the multiplication is defined we have $(y^i, f^j)(y^I,f^J)=(y^{i+(-1)^j I},f^{j+J})$. (Again the indices are to be calculated mod $7$ and mod $4$ respectively.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Just to sum up, whenever I am asked to find homomorphisms between $\mathbb{Z}_n$ and $\mathbb{Z}_n$, will all of them have the form $\alpha_r : y^m \rightarrow y^{mr}$?

Comment: Yes, $y$ must go somewhere, so $y\mapsto y^r$ and then since i's a homomorphism $y^m\mapsto y^{mr}$. Of course when $n$ is not prime these are not all automorphisms.

Comment: I supposed that it also could be $y \rightarrow my$, I have also seen that in some documents. I guess it is actually the same.

Comment: Yes, if you write the group additively then it is exactly the same thing. [And in my experience writing the bottom group additively is often the best choice.]